# Entity Framework: object returns with an empty list at first, but then suddenly the list is populated correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, circular-dependency

I have the following class:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<User> Connections { get; set; }

   //other properties

   public User()
   {
    Connections = new List<User>();
   }
}
```

Then I have a DataContext class for storage:

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
 {
     public DataContext() { }

     public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

     public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
 }
```

And a UserService class:

```
public class UserService: IUserService
{
   private DataContext _context;

   public UserService(DataContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }

   public User GetById(int id)
   {
      return _context.Users.Find(id);
   }
   ...
}
```

Now suppose I correctly stored 2 users, and I add each other to their respective connection lists.

The problem is in the following piece of code:

```
var user1 = _userService.GetById(userId);

 ---> Here user1.Connections is an empty list (unexpected)

var results = anotherList.Select(x=> 
{

   ---> Here user1.Connections have one object inside (the other user as expected)

});
```

I thought it was because the List was not populated yet since it was never accessed yet, but I also have a problem with the following endpoint in a controller:

```
var userId = int.Parse(User.Identity.Name);

var user1 = _userService.GetById(userId);

var connectionsInfo = user1.Connections.Select(x => new
{
   Id = x.Id,
   //map other properties
});

return Ok(connectionsInfo);
//this time an empty list is returned in the response, instead of a list with a single object
```

I read it might be regarding circular dependency, but I don't get any exception.

Also, I do not understand why in one case the list is populated after and in the other case is not populated at all.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Probably, you need to use [loading related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

Comment: Use Include...but this could be a problem with circular dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Also I do not understand why in one case the list is populated after and in the other case is not populated at all.*

It's the `Lazy Loading` feature in the entity framework. Lazy loading means **delaying** the loading of related data until you specifically request for it. For more explanation and a deep dive, you can review [this good article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx).

[Entity Framework supports three ways to load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) - eager loading, lazy loading, and explicit loading. for your scenario, It would prefer to use eager loading way. for achieving this goal EF has the [`Include()`](https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include) method. so, you can update your `GetById` method as below:

```
public User GetById(int id)
{
   return _context.Users
             .Include(item => item.Connections)
             .Find(id);
}
```

With the above query when you find a specific user, its connections loads at the same time too. good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed works as expected now. I still do not understand why in my last example (calling an endpoint in a controller) it returns an empy list tough. Why doesn't returning the list in a HttpResponse trigger the loading?